# Search hidden text in PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I'm using PDF.js to view PDF files typeset using LaTeX in my website. I have hidden certain text in the PDF which is searchable when use Acrobat Reader. Is there a way I can search hidden text using PDF.js?